# Deutscher Wortschatz zur (Aus-)Bildung. Studium, Studie, Bildung, Ausbildung, Bereich, Fach

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, vocabulary

Ich kann den Unterschied zwischen folgenden Wörtern nicht verstehen. Die Übersetzung hilft nicht. Vielleicht können Sie mit dem richtigen Kontext helfen, um den Unterschied erfaßbar zu machen.

**1. das Studium *vs.* die Studie**
Ich verstehe, dass das "Studium" ein Prozess des Ausbildungserhalts und die "Studie" eine wissenschaftliche Untersuchung ist (z.m. ins Geschichte). Aber habe ich die Wörter als "Bachelorstudie" oder "Masterstudie" gesehen.

**2. Bildung vs. Ausbildung**
Gibt es einen bedeutenden Unterschied zwischen diesen Wörtern?

**3. Bereich, Fach, Fachbereich**
Hier auch... Was ist der Unterschied?

Es wäre sehr schön, wenn Sie den Gebrauch im Kontext darstellen könnten, sdaß die Unterschiede verständlicher werden.
Dankeschön.

Comment: Die genannten Begriffe sind teilweise _sehr_ allgemein und umfassend. Mir würde es beispielsweise schwer fallen, eine halbwegs kurze Definition für "Bildung" anzugeben. Möglicherweise ist es sinnvoll, diese Frage in mehrere Fragen aufzuteilen.

Comment: Eigentlich wäre es die Aufgabe eines Wörterbuches wie DWDS (https://www.dwds.de) oder Wiktionary, solche Begriffe zu definieren, zumal diese Begriffe fast alle mehrere Bedeutungen haben. Mir ist nicht wirklich klar, was ich schreiben kann, was man nicht dort besser nachlesen kann. Außer vielleicht , dass "Bachelorstudie" oder "Masterstudie" **keine** üblichen Begriffe sind und dass fast alle Wörter, die du vergleichst, sehr unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben.

Comment: Ich habe die Orthographischen Fehler korrigiert und den Titel in dieselbe Sprache wie die Frage übersetzt.

Comment: Zur Verwirrung trägt vielleicht bei, das _Studien_ der Plural sowohl von _Studium_ als auch _Studie_ ist.

Answer (score 4):

Das Problem bei allen genannten Ausdrücken ist, daß sich die Bedeutungen teilweise überlappen, wenn sich auch die "Zentren" der jeweiligen Bedeutung unterscheiden.

**Ad 1.)**
"Studium" ist einerseits das Erhalten einer - üblicherweise universitären - Ausbildung, andererseits aber auch allgemein das Vertiefen seines Wissenstandes zu einem bestimmten Thema.

> das Studium der Rechtswissenschaften
> das Studium der Zeitungsenten

Im ersten Fall ist eine reguläre juristische Ausbildung an der Universität gemeint, im zweiten Fall lediglich die intensive Beschäftigung mit einem bestimmten Phänomen.

"Studie" hingegen ist eine Arbeit (Publikation) mit wissenschaftlichem Anspruch, die auch formal gewissen Ansprüchen an wissenschaftliche Arbeiten genügt - zum Unterschied etwa zum *Artikel*, der *These*, dem *Positionspapier* und dergleichen. Wenn von "Bachelorstudien" oder "Masterstudien" die Rede ist, dann vermute ich (mangels gegebenem Kontext), daß es sich dabei um Studien handelt, die als schriftliche Arbeiten zur Erlangung des Bachelor- oder Mastergrades eingereicht wurden. Früher hat man sowas (insbesondere Masterarbeiten) mit dem Fremdwort "Diplomarbeit" bezeichnet, heute heißt sowas auf Deutsch "Thesis" und wird von Leuten verfaßt, die Junggesellen (das ist die Übersetzung von "Bachelor") sind.

**Ad 2.)**
"Bildung" hat ebenfalls mehrere Bedeutungen. Zunächst ist damit der Erwerb von Wissen als geordneter Prozeß gemeint.

> Im Bereich der Bildung muß ...

Hier könnte man auch ersetzen: an den Schulen, Hochschulen, in Lehrbetrieben und dgl. - überall, wo Wissen in geregelter Form vermittelt wird.

Daneben beschreibt "Bildung" auch eine Art generalisiertes Wissen, das nicht einem bestimmten Fachbereich zugeordnet werden kann. "Allgemeinbildung" wäre dafür ein Synonym, "education" eine passende englische Übersetzung. Wenn jemand "gebildet" ist, dann muß er nicht notwendigerweise ein Studium absolviert haben, aber vermutlich kann er mehr zu einer Diskussion über Literatur, Musik, Philosophie und ähnliche Themen beitragen als jemand, der "ungebildet" ist.

"Ausbildung" ist der - geregelte - Wissenserwerb in Bezug auf eine bestimmte Fachrichtung. Ein "Studium" (an einer Universität) ist etwa eine solche Ausbildung (zum Juristen, Philosophen, Betriebswirten, Mathematiker, ...), ebenso aber eine "Lehre" ("apprenticeship" oder "traineeship"), die zum Maurer, Schlosser, Verkäufer, ... ausbildet und andere, vergleichbare Prozesse. Wer etwa zu einer Flugschule geht, wird dort zum Piloten *ausgebildet*, wer in die Fahrschule geht, bekommt eine *Ausbildung* in Sachen Steuerung eines Kraftfahrzeugs.

**Ad 3.)**
"Bereich" ist ein Unterabschnitt von irgendwas größerem und nicht weiter spezifisch. Wer etwa Schmerzen *im Bereich des Halses* hat, dem kann alles mögliche zwischen Kinn und Schlüsselbein weh tun, aber weder der Arm noch der Bauch sind davon betroffen. Es kann natürlich sein, daß eine bestimmte Studienrichtung an einer Universität als *Teil dieser Unversität* aufgefaßt wird. Dann (aber eben nur dann) sind "Bereich" und "Fachbereich" praktisch Synonyme.

Hier hängt die Bedeutung, die ein Begriff hat, stark vom Kontext ab und ich vermute (aufgrund der Auswahl Deiner Begriffe), daß jener Kontext, an dem Du interessiert bist, der *universitäre Bereich* (also: jener Teil der Gesamtwirklichkeit, der mit Universitäten zu tun hat) ist.

"Fach" verhält sich ähnlich. Generell ist ein "Fach" (das Wort hat auch andere Bedeutungen, auf die ich hier nicht eingehe) ein spezialisiertes Wissensgebiet. Es gibt das *Fach* "Naturwissenschaften", das sich untergliedert in die *Fächer* Physik, Chemie, Biologie, ..., die Chemie kennt die Fächer Stöchiometrie, Organische Chemie, Anorganische Chemie, etc..

Daneben ist "Fach" auch die Bezeichnung für - mit eben diesen spezialisierten Themen beschäftigten - Unterrichtsveranstaltungen, sowohl an Universitäten als auch anderen Ausbildungsstätten. Wer zum Beispiel Mathematiker werden will, der hat die Fächer (= Themen von Vorlesungen, Seminare, Übungen, Klausuren, ...) "Stochastik", "Lineare Algebra" und "Analysis" (neben vielen anderen). Wenn er auf die Klausur über Lineare Algebra eine schlechte Note bekommt, dann ist er *im Fach Lineare Algebra durchgefallen*.

Kommen wir zum "Fachbereich". Das ist eine Zusammensetzung aus den oben erklärten Worten "Fach" und "Bereich" und sollte - sofern meine Erklärungen was wert waren - eigentlich aus dem Zusammenhang verständlich sein. Es bezeichnet eine Unterordnung einer Universität, die meist mehrere Institute mit ähnlicher Ausrichtung zusammenfaßt - ein Synonym wäre "Fakultät". Es könnte etwa ein Institut für Organische und eins für Anorganische Chemie geben, die aber im *Fachbereich Chemie* zusammengefaßt sind. An der Spitze einer solchen Fakultät steht dabei ein *Dekan*.

Sprache lebt vom Kontext und Selbstverständliches kann auch weggelassen werden. (Für, wie Mathematiker es ausdrücken würden, "hinreichende Werte von 'selbstverständlich'".) Es kann also durchaus vom *Bereich* die Rede sein, wenn allen klar ist (sein müßte), daß es sich um den *Fachbereich* handelt.